# How to use spring aop to log cost time of method annotated with @RequestMapping?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I'd like to log cost time of all method annotated with @RequestMapping. However below code doesn't work.

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class LogAop {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    public void req() {}

    @Before("req()")
    public void logMethod(JoinPoint jp) {
        String methodName = jp.getSignature().getName();
    }


 @Around("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    public Object doAroundController(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info(" method {} begin",
                pjp.getSignature().getName());

        Object o;

        try {
            o = pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            long costTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - begin;
            log.info(" method {} ended  cost time {}ms",
                    pjp.getSignature().getName(), costTime);
        }

        return o;
    }

}
```

Both `doAroundController` and `logMethods` don't work.

If I change code above to code below, that will work:

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
public void publicMethod() {}




@Around("publicMethod()")
public Object doAroundController(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
```

In applicationContext.xml, I enable spring aop using this line:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd"
       default-autowire="byType" default-lazy-init="true">
...
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

Using JDK 7, Spring MVC 2.5.6, AspectJ 1.7.2.

Comment: Just from looking at the code (not having executed it), I see no reason why it would not work. The syntax seems to be correct. Can you maybe post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)including Maven build on GitHub? Maybe there is a subtle error in the configuration or your target classes are not Spring components. Hard to tell without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like that and it works (most important change: `within` instead of `annotation`). I'm not sure now, but I think I wanted to achive the same functionality and couldn't do it that way, so I added aspect on every method in the controller, since they all are annotated with `@RequestMapping` anyway (or at least should be).

```java
@Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController)")
void restController() {}

@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
void publicMethod() {}

@Before("restController() && publicMethod()")
void myMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer a bit, maybe it will fit your needs.

Comment: Still not work. Don't know why.. I think `@Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController)")` may be the problem because if I don't use it, it work like I expect.

Comment: Well without it, it just takes all public methods. I have it exactly like in my answer and it works on every method in all controllers. Do you have your project on github or something like that? Maybe later I will try to do the smallest possible project with aspect example and post it on mine.

Comment: This answer is incorrect because the OP asked to intercept annotated methods, which is done via `@annotation()`, indeed. The suggested `@within()` matches based on annotations on the containing class/type. As `@RequestMapping` is permitted for both methods and types, maybe the two should be combined via `||` (logical OR).